# How to escape slash in html attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm using emoji picker, everything works fine until I use this code `:/` as smiley, but I get error.

Here is the part which related to pick and convert title attribute to textarea :

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.mbEmoticons= {
        author:"Matteo Bicocchi",
        version:"1.0",
        smilesPath:"../path/to/sm/",
        smiles: {
            ":)":      "sm0",
            ":/":      "sm1"
        },
        smilesVariations: {
            ":-)": "smile",
            ":)": "smile"
        },
        smileBoxBtn:"#smileBoxBtn"
        ,
        getRegExp:function(){
            var ret="/";
            $.each($.mbEmoticons.smilesVariations,function(i){
                var emot= i.replace(/\)/g,"\\)").replace(/\(/g, "\\(").replace(/\|/g, "\\|").replace(/\*/g, "\\*").replace(/\^/g, "\\^");
                ret +="("+emot+")|";
            });
            ret+="/g";
            return eval(ret);
        },
        addSmilesBox:function(){
            $(this).each(function(){
                var textarea=$(this);
                var wrapper=$("<span/>").addClass("mbSmilesWrapper");
                textarea.wrapAll(wrapper);
                textarea.data("caret",textarea.caret());
                textarea.data("smilesIsOpen",true);
                var smilesBox=$("<div/>").addClass("mbSmilesBox").hide();
                var smilesButton=$("<span/>").addClass("mbSmilesButton").html(":-)").emoticonize();
                $.each($.mbEmoticons.smiles,function(i){
                    var emoticon=$("<span/>").addClass("emoticon").html(i).attr("title",i);
                    smilesBox.append(emoticon);
                    emoticon.emoticonize().data("emoticon",i);
                });
```

Any idea why this happen and how to solve this?

Plugin : [jQuery emoji picker](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Animated-Emoji-Picker-Plugin-jQuery-mb-emoticons.html)

Comment: Seems that you did not pasted whole code. Try `:\/` instead of `:/` - seems that you are using RegExp in your code so you have to escape the `/` :)

Comment: @DamianDziaduch , i did that,but didn't work,still getting error